# React Native, How to make a ScrollView load minimum fullscreen without scrollbar but then scroll as content grows

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I have a `ScrollView` that is being problematic because I need to put a bottom border on it, so I need it to load initially as fullscreen, but be able to have the ScrollView automatically increase in height when an `<ErrorSection />` component is added.

It doesn't seem to work with just `flex: 1`, so I am trying to explicitly declare the `height` and `width` of the ScrollView, but that is also yielding unpredictable results.

Here's my current code for the ScrollView:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native'
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable'

const E1ScrollView = ({ children, animation, style, bottomBorder }) => {
    const { container, E1bottomBorder } = styles

    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window')
    // const pxHeight = height * PixelRatio.get()
    // const pxWidth = width * PixelRatio.get()

    return (
        <ScrollView style={[container, style]}>
            <Animatable.View
                style={[{ height, width }, (bottomBorder) ? E1bottomBorder : null]}
                animation={animation}
                iterationCount={1}>

                {children}
            </Animatable.View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },
    E1bottomBorder: {
        borderBottomWidth: 5,
        borderColor: '#DD0426',
    }
})

export { E1ScrollView }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this after much research. Here is my scrolling view component fully functional:

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable'

const E1ScrollView = ({ children, animation, bottomBorder, style }) => {
    const { container, E1bottomBorder } = styles

    // the key is flexGrow: 1 on the ScrollView (and contentContainerStyle)
    // The wrapped <View /> should be flex: 1
    return (
        <ScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
            scrollEnabled>

            <Animatable.View
                style={[container, (bottomBorder) ? E1bottomBorder : null, style]}
                animation={animation}
                iterationCount={1}>

                {children}
            </Animatable.View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F0F0F0',
        flexDirection: 'column'
    },
    E1bottomBorder: {
        borderBottomWidth: 5,
        borderColor: '#DD0426',
    }
})

export { E1ScrollView }
```

If you would like to sample it, simply import that "common" component in to whatever screen you plan to use it and do this:

```
import { E1ScrollView } from '../common'
// ...
// Notice how you can overwrite styles by adding style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }} to <E1ScrollView />
return (
     <E1ScrollView animation="fadeIn" bottomBorder>
        <View style={{ flex: 0 }}><Text>test</Text></View>
        <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <Text>test</Text>
            <Text>test</Text>
            <Text>test</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />
        <View style={{ flex: 0 }}><Text>test</Text></View>
    </E1ScrollView>
)
```

The part I would like to make sure you're aware of is you can create `<CardSection />` View elements that have either `flex: 0` or `flex: 1` style and you will get effortless stacking. Then, you just need to work with margins and padding.

The `<View style={{ flex: 1 }} />` element as I demonstrated above is a critical design element to be aware of, in my opinion. I found it somewhere along my journeys and it makes filling areas pretty effortless.

If your screen receives props that add DOM elements, your view will respond in an expected manner.